# iOS 8 view isn't removed from stack after dismissViewControllerAnimated is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is my first post on SO, but I am very familiar with the site. I currently have an app that was working correctly until a recent iOS update. Here is the situation:

I have a PageViewController with a page that holds a TableViewController. When the phone orientation is changed from portrait to landscape, a modal view is created and presented to the user, using a modal segue. If the user then changes the orientation of the phone back to portrait, the app crashes.

I have spent many long hours trying to do work arounds and find/create solutions, but no luck. What I have discovered is "dismissViewControllerAnimated" is being called and the modal view is being deallocated. However, I have a print statement in at the beginning of my "orientationChanged" function. It prints once after the first time from landscape to portrait. But if the user rotates the phone to landscape again and back to portrait, "orientationChanged" will now be called twice, as though the view controller was never removed from the stack. If the user proceeds to do this 10 times, for example, on the 10th time "orientationChanged" will be called 10 times in a row.

This just doesn't make any sense to me. If the modal view is being deallocated, then how is this possible? Is there a copy of the modal view being stored somewhere? I tried to change the modal segue to be a push segue, but no luck. It would result in the same thing. Using the push segue and navigation bar that comes with it, I was able to navigate backwards through the view stack. The stack had duplicate copies of my desired modal view, like they were never removed from the stack, and at the bottom of the stack was my TableViewController.

Here is my orientationChanged function:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(popModalView ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    NSLog(@"Index:%lu",(unsigned long)self.pageIndex);
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && popModalView == NO)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayGraphNumberOfJobs" sender:self];
        popModalView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) && popModalView == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"dismiss");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        popModalView = NO;
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DisplayGraphNumberOfJobs"])
    {
        GraphJobTotalsVC *graphJobs = [segue destinationViewController];
        //initialize graphJobs...
    }
}
```

As a side note, my PageViewController has 3 pages, each with the same problem as this one. So solving one page should solve them all, hopefully. I have looked all over apple's documentation, but no luck. I have looked at countless other SO answers as well. I hope someone can help me. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: How can the user change orientation back and forth 10 times if the app crashes after the first time?

Comment: Where are you adding/removing yourself to/from NSNotificationCenter as an observer? Try moving this to viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear respectively. I'm assuming the NotificationCenter keeps a strong reference to your objects.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Tim. I am able to do it multiple times in debug mode with this hack I created, but it won't work long term. As for the NSNotificationCenter, I am new to iOS within the past month. Are you referring to adding the modal controller to the NotificationCenter? Or are you referring to it in the TableViewController?

Comment: I am referring to the class [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/). Most likely, you're adding you're adding one of your view controllers as an Observer to get notified about the orientation changes.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! The TableViewController was being added as an observer every time it appeared, but never being removed. Thank you! I have one question for you though. As you can see in the code I provided, I was dismissing the modal view in the oreientationChanged function. Now that the TableViewController is being removed as an observer, that function never gets called to dismiss the modal. Where do I now put the code to dismiss the modal?

Comment: If you add the tableViewController each time it appears, and remove it each time it disappears, then your callback function should still get called.

Comment: I've got a solution! Thank you so much Tim! If I could mark you comment as correct, I would!